# Запуск нескольких файлов Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, windows-10, pycharm

Возникла потребность запускать более трех файлов .py, но столкнулся с такой проблемой, которая в PyCharm перегружает полностью ПК. Однако, через сам IDE Python идет все ровно.

Каким "методом" или способом можно одновременно (или последовательно) исполнить все файлы .py в определенной папке?

P.S. Сами программы в папке зациклены и не выводят результаты.

Comment: план б. сделать 4й .ру в который импортировать все 3 и запустить отдельными потоками через threading

Comment: пробывал, немного не то что я хотел.

Comment: @xxxHEKETOSxxx а, что вы хотели? Почему не устраивает предложенный вариант в комментариях? Если есть какие-то ограничения, дайте нам знать [дополнив вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1288858/edit)

Comment: нехотелось бы использовать многопоточность... интересует способ открытия нескольких файлов Python одновременно, но не использовать сам Python.

Comment: прочитал статью (не по теме!), есть кое-какие элементы запуска через .bat файлы... Вот ищу подробности про это.

Comment: бат файлы запускают последовательно. пока 1й не завершиться 2й не стартанёт. в вашем случае где '''Сами программы зациклены''' запустится только 1й.

Comment: ясно....батник не подходит, есть еще какие варики?

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess


files = ["foo.py", "bar.py", "foobar.py"]  # файлы, которые нужно запустить
for file in files:
    subprocess.Popen(args=["start", "python", file], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Суть этого кода, что он посылает команды в терминал и запускает её. Для каждого файла открывается **новый** терминал. Этот код гарантированно работает на windows, на linux не проверял (там надо немного по-другому вроде как посылать аргументы, поправьте в комментариях если не прав).

Из недостатков такое решение проблематично дебажить (если это очень важно).

В зависимости от задачи можешь получать нужные файлы через модуль os и посылать дополнительные аргументы, дополнив список в аргументе *args* в *subprocess.Popen*, если в скрипте они вытаскиваются через sys.argv, argparse и прочие библиотеки для работы с CLI.

Comment: спасибо, щас проверю

Comment: Вроде как запускает, однако через пару секунд терминалы закрываются...